# Method calling "await axios.post" and returning result is not blocked

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a method call as follows:

```
 let initialFormValues = fetchAgreement(queryStr.get("id"));
 // Modify certain fields afterwards...
 initialFormValues['test'] = 'abc';
```

The method is an Axios POST with an `await` as follows:

```
const fetchAgreement = async (id) => {
    const url = '/api/agreements/fetchAgreementForm';
    try {
        let obj = {'id': parseInt(id)};
        const response = await axios.post(url, obj);
        return response.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
         //...
    }
```

I see that the method call in Snippet #1 is **not** blocked. In other words, before I'm done, I go on to the next line, `initialFormValues['test'] = 'abc';`. But why? I specifically forced Axios to `await`. How can I accomplish that?

BTW, if I remove `async`, I get the error `Unexpected reserved word 'await'`, so I can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetchAgreement is an async method (returns a Promise), therefore you must await it too or only proceed after it has fullfilled, something like this:

```
let initialFormValues = await fetchAgreement(queryStr.get("id"));

initialFormValues['test'] = 'abc';
```

OR

```
let initialFormValues = // default values;

fetchAgreement(queryStr.get("id"))
.then((data) => {
  // use data as needed
  initialFormValues['test'] = 'abc';
});
```

Comment: If I do that, `Unexpected reserved word 'await' ` on this usage:  `let initialFormValues = await fetchAgreement(queryStr.get("id"));`

Comment: You get the error `Unexpected reserved word 'await'` because await is only allowed inside async scopes. New versions of node allows TOP LEVELS await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top-level-await

Comment: Use the promise.then syntax and it will work fine @geneb.